# jQuery why json object width key 0 is converted in array

Tags: php, jquery

A very strange thing has given me headaches.

Here are my example:

PHP:

```
$my_obj1 = ["0" => "something"];
$my_obj1 = json_encode($my_obj1);

$my_obj2 = ["1" => "something else"];
$my_obj2 = json_encode($my_obj2);
```

JS:

```
var my_obj1 = <?php echo json_encode(json_decode($my_obj1))?>;
var my_obj2 = <?php echo json_encode(json_decode($my_obj2))?>;

console.log( my_obj1, my_obj2 );
//show -> ["something"] {1: "something else"}

//espected ->  {"0":"something"} {1: "something else"}
```

as I put in the comments, expected 2 objects.
but it gives me One array and one object

I use jQuery 3.1.0

Comment: Why do you `echo json_encode(json_decode($my_obj1))` instead of just `echo $my_obj1`?

Comment: You are right  but I have tryed to reproducing the real process . 1 I receive the array ... 2. Y save to data base 3. I get again from data base (for that I emulated the second json_encode)

Comment: Ah - that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option to [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to work around this issue:

```
$my_obj1 = ["0" => "something"];
$my_obj1 = json_encode($my_obj1, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $my_obj1;
```

Output:

```
{"0":"something"}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/st15L)

Comment: Yes. That is ... I need 4 min more to can accept your answer